# Preencher combobox com ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Olá, tenho uma página que mostra uma lista de usuários do sistema em uma tabela. No topo da página, tenho 3 combobox que filtram os resultados da tabela sem refresh. Preciso popular o segundo e o terceiro combo dinâmicamente e, ao mesmo tempo, ir mudando os resultados da tabela. Só que travei antes de começar a tabela rs O segundo combo eu consegui preencher de acordo com o primeiro, porém o terceiro eu não consigo popular... Alguem pode me ajudar ?

Segue o código:

```
if($funcao == 'combo1') {

    $sql = "select codfilial, nome from filial where codempresa=$codempresa order by nome;";
    $rst = my_query($connR, $sql);

    $selectfilial = "<option></option>" . getOptionSelect($rst, 'codcliente', 'nome');
    echo $selectfilial;

    exit;
}

if($funcao == 'combo2') {

    $sql = "select codequipe, nome from equipe where codempresa=$codempresa and codfilial=$codfilial order by nome";
    $rst = my_query($connR, $sql);

    $selectequipe = "<option></option>" . getOptionSelect($rst, 'codequipe', 'nome');
    echo $selectequipe;

    exit;
}

<script>
function buscarfilial(){
    $("#funcao").val("combo1");
    data = $('#formpesq').serialize();
    var jqxhr = $.ajax( {
        url: "/personificar_usuario.php",
        type: "POST",
        timeout:default_timeout,
        data: data})
        .done(function(retorno) {
            arr = retorno;
            $("#filial").replaceWith('<select class="form-control" name="filial" id="filial" style="width: 250px;">'+arr+'</select>');
        });
}

 function buscarequipe(){
    $("#funcao").val("combo2");
    data = $('#formpesq').serialize();
    var jqxhr = $.ajax( {
        url: "/personificar_usuario.php",
        type: "POST",
        timeout:default_timeout,
        data: data})
        .done(function(retorno) {
            arr = retorno;
            $("#equipe").replaceWith('<select class="form-control" name="equipe" id="equipe" style="width: 250px;">'+arr+'</select>');
        });
}
```

```
<?
        $sql = "select codempresa, nome from empresa order by nome;";
        $rst = my_query($connR, $sql);
        $selectempresa = getOptionSelect($rst, 'codempresa','nome');
        global $codempresa;
        $codempresa = $rst[0]['codempresa'];
        $codempresa = explode('|',$codempresa);
        $codempresa = $codempresa[0];


    ?>

    <div id="formulario" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="plRel" id="relpesq">
                <form class="form-inline" method="post" name="formpesq" action="/personificar_usuario.php" id="formpesq" style="margin-bottom: 0.25em; padding-top: 0.25em;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="funcao" id="funcao" value="pesquisa"/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Empresa</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="codempresa" value="codempresa" id="codempresa" onchange="javascript:buscarfilial();" style="width: 250px;"><?=$selectempresa?></select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 5px">
                        <label style="margin-left: 5px">Filial</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="filial" id="filial" style="width: 250px;"></select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 5px">
                        <label style="margin-left: 5px">Equipe</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="equipe" id="equipe" style="width: 250px;"></select>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Obrigada.

Comment: O terceiro também será preenchido com base no primeiro, ou com base no segundo?

Comment: O terceiro será preenchido de acordo com o segundo. 
Empresa > Filial > Equipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu PHP use nomes mais "amigáveis" para identificar o que faz o que.

```
<?php
    if($funcao == 'filial') {

        $sql = "select codfilial, nome from filial where codempresa=$codempresa order by nome;";
        $rst = my_query($connR, $sql);

        $selectfilial = "<option selected></option>" . getOptionSelect($rst, 'codcliente', 'nome');
        echo $selectfilial;

    } else if( $funcao == 'equipe') {

        $sql = "select codequipe, nome from equipe where codempresa=$codempresa and codfilial=$codfilial order by nome";
        $rst = my_query($connR, $sql);

        $selectequipe = "<option></option>" . getOptionSelect($rst, 'codequipe', 'nome');
        echo $selectequipe;

    }

    exit;
?>
```

Abstraia suas funções, criando apenas uma parametrizada fica mais fácil de dar manutenção. Você também não precisa ficar 
dando replace no elemento, basta reescrever o conteúdo HTML dele:

```
<script>


$(document).on('change', '#codempresa, #filial', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var target = $(this).data('target');

    $("#funcao").val(target);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/personificar_usuario.php",
        type: "POST",
        timeout:default_timeout,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $('#formpesq').serialize(),
        success: function(retorno){
            $('#' + target).html(retorno);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            console.log(textStatus, jqXHR);
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

No seu formulário coloque também o evento `onchange` no select da filial. (Antes não funcionava porque você estava reescrevendo-o com jQuery):

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" name="formpesq" action="/personificar_usuario.php" id="formpesq" style="margin-bottom: 0.25em; padding-top: 0.25em;">
    <input type="hidden" name="funcao" id="funcao" value="pesquisa"/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Empresa</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="codempresa" id="codempresa" data-target="filial" style="width: 250px;"><?=$selectempresa?></select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 5px">
        <label style="margin-left: 5px">Filial</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="filial" id="filial" data-target="equipe" style="width: 250px;"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 5px">
        <label style="margin-left: 5px">Equipe</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="equipe" id="equipe" style="width: 250px;"></select>
    </div>

</form>
```

---

<sub>Obs.: O código é mais conceitual, não foi testado e pode conter erros.</sub>

Comment: Oi Kadu. Não funcionou... Está aparecendo no console que a função buscarDados() não está definida =(

Comment: @Donnathegirl atualizei o código Javascript e o formulário. Removi os eventos das marcações HTML e coloquei em um observador de eventos do jQuery. Faça essa atualização no teu código e me diz o que acontece. ;)

Comment: Que lindo, funcionou *-* Muito obrigada pela ajuda @KaduAmaral ! Bjs