# Alterar um combobox a partir do outro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Colegas.

Tenho um combobox do qual tem a relação de hotéis:

```
<select name="Hotel" id="Hotel" class="form-control">
<option value="Selecione">Hotel</option>
<option value="Hotel A">Hotel A</option>
<option value="Hotel B">Hotel B</option>
<option value="Hotel C">Hotel C</option>
</select>
```

Só que cada hotel terá a relação das acomodações com seus respectivos valores que está em outro combobox. Vejam:

```
<select name="Acomodacao" id="Acomodacao" class="form-control">
    <option value="Selecione">Acomodação</option>
    <option value="SGL">Single Valor X</option>
    <option value="DBL">Duplo Valor X</option>
    <option value="TPL">Triplo Valor X</option>
    <option value="QDL">Quadruplo Valor X</option>
    <option value="QTP">Quintuplo Valor X</option>
</select>
```

Como eu faria para que ao selecionar um hotel, aparecesse no outro combobox a acomodação referente a ele automaticamente?

Comment: Tem isso cadastrado em algum banco de dados? Dê uma olhada aqui: [Preencher combobox com ajax](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82514/preencher-combobox-com-ajax)

Comment: Oi Cadu. Ele não está vindo do BD.

Comment: Onde você armazena as informações de relação de qual Hotel tem qual Acomodação?

Comment: Texto livre. Não vem direto do banco por ser informações fixas. Está no próprio HTML

Comment: Coloca a parte que você referencia o hotel a acomodação, ou é essa parte que você está em duvida?

Comment: você poderia atualizar a sua pergunta com uma amostra deste "texto livre"? pois neste caso é interresante se trabalhar com JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar um objeto com a lista de relações dos hotéis e suas acomodações, exemplo:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
  // Objeto com as relações de hotéis e suas respectivas acomodações disponíveis
  var acomodacoes = {
    Selecione: ['Selecione'],
    HotelA: ['Selecione', 'SGL', 'DBL', 'TPL'],
    HotelB: ['Selecione', 'SGL', 'DBL', 'TPL', 'QDL'],
    HotelC: ['Selecione', 'SGL', 'DBL', 'TPL', 'QTP']
  }
  
  // Lista de acomodações
  $acomods = $('#Acomodacao option');
  
  // Evento ao alterar o hotel
  $('#Hotel').on('change', function(event){
    // Hotel atual (selecionado)
    var hotel = this.value;
    
    // Percorre a lista de acomodações
    $acomods.each(function(index, el){
      
      // Verifica se a acomodação atual existe na relação
      // de acomodações para o hotel selecionado
      if (acomodacoes[hotel].indexOf(el.value) == -1) // Não existe
          $(el).prop('disabled', true); // Desabilita a acomodação
      else // Existe
        $(el).prop('disabled', false); // Habilita a acomodação
    });
  }).change(); // Executa o método change uma vez para desabilitar 
               // todas as acomodações pois nenhum hotel foi selecionado ainda
});
```

```css
select option[disabled] {
  /* Oculta os options que estão desabilitados */
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Hotel" id="Hotel" class="form-control">
    <option value="Selecione">Hotel</option>
    <option value="HotelA">Hotel A</option>
    <option value="HotelB">Hotel B</option>
    <option value="HotelC">Hotel C</option>
</select>
<select name="Acomodacao" id="Acomodacao" class="form-control">
    <option value="Selecione">Acomodação</option>
    <option value="SGL">Single Valor X</option>
    <option value="DBL">Duplo Valor X</option>
    <option value="TPL">Triplo Valor X</option>
    <option value="QDL">Quadruplo Valor X</option>
    <option value="QTP">Quintuplo Valor X</option>
</select>
```

Poderia ainda, como já citado nos comentários da pergunta, buscar a relação de *Hotel x Acomodações* em um arquivo JSON utilizando AJAX.

Comment: Perfeito. Funcionou corretamente :)

Answer (score 1):

faça algo tipo isso:

```
$('#Hotel').change(function() {
  var valorSelecionado = $(this).val();

  $('#Acomodacao').prop('enabled', true);
  $('#Acomodacao').prop('selected', valorSelecionado);
});
```