# Recuperar valor do banco de dados CodeIgniter - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em um formulário de usuário, eu carrego informações, como nome de usuário, senha e permissões.

Mas agora eu incluí na tabela de `permissoes` um campo chamado `grupo`.

E incluí no formulário de `usuarios` este campo, para que; toda vez que for escolhido a permissão do usuário, o campo grupo carregue o nome do grupo da permissão selecionada.

Sei que no MYSQL, a querie utilizada é

```
`SELECT `grupo` FROM `permissoes` WHERE `id` = 1`.
```

Mas não consegui fazer isto no codeigniter.

Na função editar,

Recupero os dados do usuário e exibo as informações na view da seguinte forma:

Controller Usuário

```
//Obtem dados do usuário
$this->data['usuarios']   = $this->Usuarios_model->obter_id($this->uri->segment(4));
//Obtem Permissões Ativas
$this->data['permissoes'] = $this->Permissoes_model->obter_ativo('permissoes', 'permissoes.id,permissoes.nome');
//Carrega View
$this->template->admin_render('admin/usuarios/editar', $this->data);
```

Model Usuário:

```
//Função obter ID
function obter_id($id){
    $this->db->select('usuarios.*, permissoes.nome as permissao');
    $this->db->select('usuarios.*, permissoes.grupo as grupo');
    $this->db->join('permissoes', 'usuarios.permissoes_id = permissoes.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('usuarios.id',$id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    return $this->db->get('usuarios')->row();
}
```

Model Permissões

```
//Exibir somente permissões ativas
function obter_ativo($tabela,$campos){        
    $this->db->select($campos);
    $this->db->from($tabela);
    $this->db->where('situacao',1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();;
}
```

View Usuário

```
//View do formulário usuário
<select name="permissoes_id" id="permissoes_id" class="form-control">
   <?php foreach ($permissoes as $permissao) {
      if($permissao->id == $usuarios->permissoes_id){ $selected = 'selected';}else{$selected = '';}
     echo '<option value="'.$permissao->id.'"'.$selected.'>'.$permissao->nome.'</option>';
   } ?>
</select>
<label>Grupo</label>
<input "Aqui vai o nome do grupo referente a permissão selecionada" />
```

Tabelas usuário

```
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`primeiro_nome` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
`ultimo_nome` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
`nome_usuario` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
`telefone` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
`senha` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`permissoes_id` INT NOT NULL,
`grupo` INT NOT NULL,
```

Tabelas Permissoes

```
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nome` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
`descricao` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`grupo` INT NOT NULL,
`permissoes` TEXT NULL,
`situacao` TINYINT(1) NULL,
```

Comment: Onde é o erro ou problema?

Comment: Não há erro, o que quero é recuperar o  grupo relacionado a permissão.

Comment: Veja na imagem acima, que terás uma ideia.
Para cada permissão existe um grupo.
Exemplo:
Permissão Administrador - grupo 1,
Permissão Suporte - grupo 2,
Permissão Operação - grupo 1;

Quero recuperar o grupo de acordo com a permissão selecionada.

Comment: Quem está recuperando os grupos das permissões? `obter_ativo()`?

Comment: Sim, obter_ativo()

Comment: Faz `print_r($query->result())` na saída de `obter_ativo()` e mostra aqui, _please_.

Comment: Mas imprimindo desta forma `print_r($query->result())` no model, vai me mostrar o resultado aonde?

Comment: Mas utilizando `print_r($this->data['permissoes']);`, tenho `Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nome] => Administrador
        )

)`

Comment: é a mesma coisa, mas pelo que dá pra ver, o grupo não está aí... esse objeto só tem id e nome...

Comment: Só por isto já consegui.
`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [nome] => Administrador [grupo] => 1 ) ) `

Comment: Tem como deixar dinamico?
Tipo, quando alterar o select, alterar também o grupo relacionado a permissao?

Comment: Assim: [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/185636/42307](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/185636/42307)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Select(combobox) Dinâmico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184695/selectcombobox-din%c3%a2mico)

Comment: Mas isto Naum seria na mesma tabela. Exemplo: `id = 1, permissão = admin, grupo = 1`

Comment: Não importa. A lógica é a mesma. Você só precisa fazer no seu _model_ um método para recuperar as permissões e outro para recuperar os grupos.